# Avoiding If statements in render method

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am very new and unfamiliar web development.

In my side project I keep ending up with these `If` statements in my `render()` method when I am trying to control what to render based on different things.

One example...

```
App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return {validCode: false};
    },

    handleSubmit(code){
        var result = Meteor.call('validateCode', code);
        this.setState({validCode: result});
    },

    render() {

        if(this.state.validCode){
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Valid Code!!</h1>
                    <Menu />
                    <OtherComponentsOnlyVisibleWhenAuthorized />
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <InviteCodeInput onCodeSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Basically I want to validate some user input. Based on that, I either want to display the rest of the web page components in a normal fashion or continue to display the input form component.

I just feel that having the `if` statement in the render is so darn ugly. Also I have never seen another react snippet do anything similar so I am guessing this is a no-no. Can someone familiar with react suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBH, I don't think it matters and I'm sure there are heaps of components that are written like this. Here is an example from reddit https://github.com/reddit/reddit-mobile/blob/master/src/views/components/Listing.jsx

If you must take this outside of render then just create another method for it

```
App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return {validCode: false};
    },

    handleSubmit(code){
        var result = Meteor.call('validateCode', code);
        this.setState({validCode: result});
    },

    renderValidPage() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Valid Code!!</h1>
                <Menu />
                <OtherComponentsOnlyVisibleWhenAuthorized />
            </div>
        ); 
    },

    renderInvalidPage() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <InviteCodeInput onCodeSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.validCode ? renderValidPage() : renderInvalidPage();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code is doing, but with respect to code organization inside your render method, I would do something like this:

```
render: function() {

  var validDisplay = (
    <div>
      <h1>Valid Code!!</h1>
      <Menu />
      <OtherComponentsOnlyVisibleWhenAuthorized />
    </div>
  );

  var notValidDisplay = (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <InviteCodeInput onCodeSubmit
      {this.handleSubmit}/>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    {this.state.validCode ? validDisplay : notValidDisplay}
  );

}
```

Hope this helps!